# Mounting a webcam from one computer to another over local network

Tags: ssh, webcam, input-devices, sshfs

So I have this python application on my laptop that needs to use the webcam, or more precisely the `/dev/video0` folder.

Now this application needs to use the GPU, and my laptop is not powerful enough, but I want to be able to run this application on my laptop.

I have a desktop computer that has a powerful enough GPU to do this, so I was thinking if I could make the desktop "think" that it has a webcam, by mounting the `/dev/video0` from my laptop, using `sshfs` or something similar, to the desktop.

Is there any drawbacks of doing this? Is this even possible? I wanted some advice from more experienced users before I tried this.